# Django crispy-forms shows errors above InlineRadios but below others

Tags: css, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

in model

```
class TourLead(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

in forms

```
gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=TourLead.GENDER_CHOICES)
```

Here is layout:

```
Layout(
        Field('name', placeholder='John Doe'),
        InlineRadios('gender'),
        # ...
    )
```

[image]

My question is how I can put errors **always after** input?

I've tried some css:

```
[id^="error"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but cannot figure out how display some kind of spacer (margin ...) after ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this specified custom template

```
InlineRadios('gender', template='radioselect_inline.html'),
```

simply copy it and `radioselect.html` from `site-packages/...` to your static folder and change last include in 'radioselect_inline.html' to

```
{% include 'radioselect.html' %}
```

and in `radioselect.html` move `{% include 'bootstrap3/layout/field_errors_block.html' %}` to the end like below

```
    #...
    {% endfor %}

    {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/field_errors_block.html' %}
    {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text.html' %}
</div>
```

Also at this moment you will face bug https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/issues/361 so simply downgrade to `django-crispy-forms==1.4.0` and it will work!